# Javascript - Executing all the validation functions on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, function, return

I am currently working on an Email form and have little experience with javascript but am close to accomplishing what I need but struggling at one point, spent hours trying everything I can find searching and figured someone on here would probably have my answer instantly.

I currently have 3 functions checking a box is filled, email is correct format and passwords match.
If I set each function to run on its own upon clicking submit they work perfectly for their own intended purpose, however I am having trouble working out how to make it so that all 3 functions are run upon hitting submit. My final attempt which seems closest is adding the validateForm function at the bottom of my scripts to run all scripts but this did not seem to work. Hopefully something small I am overlooking, appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<form name="registerkeys" form action="form.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
First Name:  <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name:  <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email:  <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Phone Number:  <input type="text" name="phonenumber"><br>
Information on Key:  <input type="text" name="keyinfo"><br>
Password:  <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></label><br>
Verify Password:  <input type="password" name="passwordverify" id="passwordverify"><br>
Password Hint:  <input type="text" name="passwordhint"><br>
<textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30" placeholder="Comments:"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function validateFill(){
    var x=document.forms["registerkeys"]["first_name"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
  }

    var x=document.forms["registerkeys"]["last_name"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Last name must be filled out");
        return false;
  }

    var x=document.forms["registerkeys"]["phonenumber"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Phone number must be filled out");
        return false;
  }

    var x=document.forms["registerkeys"]["keyinfo"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Key info must be filled out");
        return false;
  }

    var x=document.forms["registerkeys"]["pass1"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Password must be filled out");
        return false;
  }

    var x=document.forms["registerkeys"]["passwordhint"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Password hint must be filled out");
        return false;
  }

} 


function validateEmail()
{
var x=document.forms["registerkeys"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}


function validatePassword(){
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var passwordverify = document.getElementById("passwordverify").value;
    var ok = true;
    if (password != passwordverify) {
        alert("Passwords Do not match");
        document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        document.getElementById("passwordverify").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        ok = false;
    }
    else {
        alert("Passwords Match!!!");
    }
    return ok;
}


function validateForm(){
    var a = validateFill();
    var b = validateEmail();
    var c = validatePassword();
    return a && b && c;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `validateFill()` and `validateEmail()` function should return `true` at the end.

`validateFill()` only returns `false` if validation has not passed, but never `true`. You should add `return true` at the end of the function, outside of conditions.

`validateEmail()` returns `false` if email is invalid but you are missing the `return true` if email is valid.

Also, to prevent duplicate popups I suggest that you change your `validateForm()` to something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
 var a = validateFill();

 if (a) var b = validateEmail();
 else var b = false;

 if (a&&b) var c = validatePassword();
 else var c = false;

 return a && b && c;
}
```

So it only checks one function until it passes, and then checks the next.

Comment: Thanks, I have added return true; to the end of each function just before the curly bracket and this has not resolved the issue. Have I added this incorrectly. Apologies in advance I lack knowledge of javascript and what you see here are snippets collected from the web. Here is where im uploading for test purposes and as you can see none of the function are working. http://cjeffryes.comoj.com/

Comment: And what exactly is not working? It seems to be working for me, altough with multiple messages, but it seems to work?

Comment: Oh I see, it does work to some degree, but im finding if I fill everybox with one letter, and add passwords that dont match the form still submits. But if i leave a field empty I get errors including passwords dont match. Guessing my functions themselves need a bit of attention as they are all being run.

Comment: Seems to be working now, I added to the functions requiring the password fields to both be filled as well as email and it seems to work. I see what you mean about multiple messages, I will look into this and also remove passwords match message. Thanks a lot for your help @D.Kasipovic, much appreciated. Edit: in response to your edit i will give that a try, thank again :)

Comment: Why don't just call functions directly: `function validateForm() { return validateFill() && validateEmail() && validatePassword(); }`? If  `validateFill()` return false then other functions won't be celled and so on.

Answer (score -1):

`validateFill()` and `validateEmail()` should `return true` at the end (right now they return nothing if validation passed.

`validatePassword()` should return `true` instead of `ok`.

Comment: `ok` is a variable that is set either to true or false. Read the example.

Comment: He use two different approaches: flag in `validatePassword()` and return on error in other functions. One approach thought all code will be safer and i think in JS second is more standart

Comment: Personally I think that directly returning `false` is better because it stops function execution on the first error occured. However, it can have consequences since function never gets to the end, and that can play games with your logic.

Comment: Yep, totaly agree with you. Edited comment to be clear